# Is there a way to set a Community Theme using a Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, customer-community, community-builder

Given that I have 2 different already made themes for a community (e.g., Light Mode and Dark Mode), is there a way for a Community User to set their preferred theme via a Lightning Component, and preferably have that preference saved for later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you should be able to do this.

You can't actually swap out a whole theme component out, but you can wrap it in different css - then you can define two different sets of css in the css file.

Then, just handle a change theme event to toggle the theme.

```
<aura:attribute name="theme" type="String" default="light"/>

<div class="{!v.theme}">
    <div class="searchRegion">
        {!v.search}
    </div>
    <div class="profileMenuRegion">
        {!v.profileMenu}
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
        {!v.navBar}
    </div>
    <div class="newHeader">
        {!v.newHeader}
    </div>
    <div class="mainContentArea">
        {!v.body}
    </div>
</div>
```

In the CSS class, you'd go:

```
.THIS.light .your_other_classes {
  background-color:#ffffff;
  //etc
}

.THIS.dark .your_other_classes {
  background-color:#000000;
  //etc
}
```

You could then remember the theme in localstorage:

```
var storeTheme = window.localStorage.getItem('storeTheme');

if (storeTheme == 'true'){
  component.set("v.theme",window.localStorage.getItem('theme'));
}
```

Hopefully that'll do it!

Comment: Note the css because it's the outer div its `.THIS.light` not `.THIS .light`

Comment: Thanks so much. I was beyond lost. Lightning as a whole isn't my strong point, CSS never made sense to me, and Community Builder is something I literally learned on Monday, so this is a lot at once. This makes sense now, I just need to make a listener and trigger the value to be changed. Sounds very easy.

Comment: Yep, it should be reasonably easy. You are doing well given you've had four days with it!

Comment: I'm definately getting carried by those around me, for sure. I'm kind of in a trial by fire as my first position, for sure. Not sure how to feel about it, but I'm trying at least.

Comment: I did eventually take this and make it do what I (and those above me) wanted. Got some logic to flip back and forth and the push of a button and a way to assign the view they are looking at as their default. All is well.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible through `forceCommunity:themeLayout` interface.

Sample component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:themeLayout" access="global" description="Sample Custom Theme Layout">
    <aura:attribute name="search" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="profileMenu" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="navBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newHeader" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <div>
        <div class="searchRegion">
            {!v.search}
        </div>
        <div class="profileMenuRegion">
            {!v.profileMenu}
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            {!v.navBar}
        </div>
        <div class="newHeader">
            {!v.newHeader}
        </div>
        <div class="mainContentArea">
            {!v.body}
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm

Comment: You would need to define both light and dark css in this theme file, scoped by a css class. then handle an application event eg changeThemeEvent. in the handler, you'd change the theme class in your outer div.

Comment: So, there would be a way for a user with only Community access to press a button in a custom Lightning component to be able to set all of the FALSE values to true, but that would affect all users. 

Is there a way for a user's personal view to be different based on pressing a button in the community?

Comment: @CasparHarmer That's exactly what I was getting at! So there's a way for a user to flip between the 2 CSS files based on their preference, in this case, yeah?

Comment: if you do like I describe, you could set the desired theme and store as a cookie or other browser storage.

Comment: I'll give you a quick answer - won't be long